# GA4 Data Not Retained for More Than 60 Days Despite BigQuery Table Expiration Set to 'Never

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I've recently linked my Credit Card and upgraded my Google BigQuery settings and set the table expiration to 'never' in hopes of retaining my Google Analytics 4 (GA4) data for more than a year. However, I've observed that GA4 is not retaining data for more than 60 days.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue? How did you resolve it? Is there something I might be overlooking?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your `Data Retention` setting in GA4 UI

[image]